# Adding email to payment_method.billing_details in Stripe confirmCardSetup doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments

I use Setup Intents API that lets you save a customer’s card without an initial payment. In addition to the payment details I want to process and see in the stripe dashboard here other information like email.

But this:

```
stripe
      .confirmCardSetup(setupIntent.client_secret, {
        payment_method: {
          card: card,
          billing_details: { email: email }
        }
```

doesn't work. I can't see email in post req.

Thank you for your help

In the example below I attach the reduced code, where I try to attach to customer EMAIL. If you need to see the full logic, the code is taken from this sample: https://github.com/stripe-samples/saving-card-without-payment

### script.js

```
var stripeElements = function(publicKey, setupIntent) {
  var stripe = Stripe(publicKey);
  var elements = stripe.elements();

  // Element styles
  var style = {
    base: {
      fontSize: "16px",
      color: "#32325d",
      fontFamily:
        "-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, sans-serif",
      fontSmoothing: "antialiased",
      "::placeholder": {
        color: "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)"
      }
    }
  };

  var card = elements.create("card", { style: style });

  card.mount("#card-element");

  // Element focus ring
  card.on("focus", function() {
    var el = document.getElementById("card-element");
    el.classList.add("focused");
  });

  card.on("blur", function() {
    var el = document.getElementById("card-element");
    el.classList.remove("focused");
  });

  // Handle payment submission when user clicks the pay button.
  var button = document.getElementById("submit");
  button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    changeLoadingState(true);
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;

    stripe
      .confirmCardSetup(setupIntent.client_secret, {
        payment_method: {
          card: card,
          billing_details: { email: email }
        }
      })
      .then(function(result) {
        if (result.error) {
          changeLoadingState(false);
          var displayError = document.getElementById("card-errors");
          displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
        } else {
          // The PaymentMethod was successfully set up
          orderComplete(stripe, setupIntent.client_secret);
        }
      });
  });
};

var getSetupIntent = function(publicKey) {
  return fetch("/create-setup-intent", {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(setupIntent) {
      stripeElements(publicKey, setupIntent);
    });
};

var getPublicKey = function() {
  return fetch("/public-key", {
    method: "get",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      getSetupIntent(response.publicKey);
    });
};

// Show a spinner on payment submission
var changeLoadingState = function(isLoading) {
  if (isLoading) {
    document.querySelector("button").disabled = true;
    document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.remove("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.add("hidden");
  } else {
    document.querySelector("button").disabled = false;
    document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.add("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.remove("hidden");
  }
};

/* Shows a success / error message when the payment is complete */
var orderComplete = function(stripe, clientSecret) {
  stripe.retrieveSetupIntent(clientSecret).then(function(result) {
    var setupIntent = result.setupIntent;
    var setupIntentJson = JSON.stringify(setupIntent, null, 2);

    document.querySelector(".sr-payment-form").classList.add("hidden");
    document.querySelector(".sr-result").classList.remove("hidden");
    document.querySelector("pre").textContent = setupIntentJson;
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.querySelector(".sr-result").classList.add("expand");
    }, 200);

    changeLoadingState(false);
  });
};

getPublicKey();
```

### server.js (nodejs)

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const { resolve } = require("path");
// Copy the .env.example in the root into a .env file in this folder
const env = require("dotenv").config({ path: "./.env" });

const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, {
  apiVersion: '2020-08-27',
  appInfo: { // For sample support and debugging, not required for production:
    name: "stripe-samples/saving-card-without-payment",
    version: "0.0.1",
    url: "https://github.com/stripe-samples/saving-card-without-payment"
  }
});

try {
  app.use(express.static(process.env.STATIC_DIR));
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Missing env file, be sure to copy .env.example to .env");
}

app.use(
  express.json({
    // We need the raw body to verify webhook signatures.
    // Let's compute it only when hitting the Stripe webhook endpoint.
    verify: function(req, res, buf) {
      if (req.originalUrl.startsWith("/webhook")) {
        req.rawBody = buf.toString();
      }
    }
  })
);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const path = resolve(process.env.STATIC_DIR + "/index.html");
  res.sendFile(path);
});

app.get("/public-key", (req, res) => {
  res.send({ publicKey: process.env.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY });
});

app.post("/create-setup-intent", async (req, res) => {
  // Create or use an existing Customer to associate with the SetupIntent.
  // The PaymentMethod will be stored to this Customer for later use.
  const customer = await stripe.customers.create();

  res.send(await stripe.setupIntents.create({
    customer: customer.id
  }));
});

// Webhook handler for asynchronous events.
app.post("/webhook", async (req, res) => {
  let data;
  let eventType;

  // Check if webhook signing is configured.
  if (process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET) {
    // Retrieve the event by verifying the signature using the raw body and secret.
    let event;
    let signature = req.headers["stripe-signature"];

    try {
      event = await stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
        req.rawBody,
        signature,
        process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.`);
      return res.sendStatus(400);
    }
    // Extract the object from the event.
    data = event.data;
    eventType = event.type;
  } else {
    // Webhook signing is recommended, but if the secret is not configured in `config.js`,
    // retrieve the event data directly from the request body.
    data = req.body.data;
    eventType = req.body.type;
  }

  if (eventType === "setup_intent.created") {
    console.log(`  A new SetupIntent is created. ${data.object.id}`);
  }

  if (eventType === "setup_intent.setup_failed") {
    console.log(`  A SetupIntent has failed to set up a PaymentMethod.`);
  }

  if (eventType === "setup_intent.succeeded") {
    console.log(
      `  A SetupIntent has successfully set up a PaymentMethod for future use.`
    );
  }

  if (eventType === "payment_method.attached") {
    console.log(
      `  A PaymentMethod ${data.object.id} has successfully been saved to a Customer ${data.object.customer}.`
    );

    // At this point, associate the ID of the Customer object with your
    // own internal representation of a customer, if you have one.

    // Optional: update the Customer billing information with billing details from the PaymentMethod
    const customer = await stripe.customers.update(
      data.object.customer,
      {email: data.object.billing_details.email},
      () => {
        console.log(
          `  Customer successfully updated.`
        );
      }
    );

  }

  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen(4242, () => console.log(`Node server listening on port ${4242}!`));
```

### index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Saving a Card sample</title>
    <meta name="description" content="A demo of Stripe Payment Intents" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css" />
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="sr-root">
      <div class="sr-main">
        <div class="sr-payment-form card">
          <div class="sr-form-row">
            <label>
              Account details
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email address" />
          </div>

          <div class="sr-form-row">
            <label>
              Payment details
            </label>
            <div class="sr-input sr-element sr-card-element" id="card-element">
              <!-- A Stripe card Element will be inserted here. -->
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="sr-field-error" id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
          <button id="submit">
            <div class="spinner hidden" id="spinner"></div>
            <span id="button-text">Link your card to your account</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="sr-result hidden">
          <p>Card setup completed<br /></p>
          <pre>
            <code></code>
          </pre>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your own text input fields (and validate them) to collect the customer's email and name.

Once you have that, you pass it along under the `billing_details` hash like you already are passing email:

```
    stripe
      .confirmCardSetup(setupIntent.client_secret, {
        payment_method: {
          card: card,
          billing_details: {
            email: email,
            name: name,
          },
        },
[...]
```

Comment: thank you. Unfortunately, my email is still not showing up in the stripe dashboard. I did a simple validation in javascript using regex - or did you mean some "special" validation? I'll change code in my question in a sec

Comment: my email is still not showing up in the stripe dashboard -> are you passing it? you can view your requests in the Stripe Dashboard at https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/ and see what your requests are passing to Stripe

Comment: no, there is no email in req post https://snipboard.io/pnsvBe.jpg @hmunoz

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out that I made a completely stupid mistake. I forgot to switch the running webhook from live to test key.